# How to run WCF service and Silverlight 3 client app in one VS debug session

Tags: wcf, silverlight, debugging

Is this possible?  I have a solution with both projects, I just want to be able to hit F5 and debug both client and server at the same time.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer to this one.  In VS:

1. Right-click on the solution in the Solution Explorer window, and select Properties.
2. Select the Startup Projects property page.
3. Select Multiple Startup Projects
4. Choose the Projects that you want to startup on F5

Answer (score 1):

If I were doing this I would open the solution twice - two instances of visual studio - once for each thing being debugged.